# How to get a new solution with high probability from previously found, incomplete solutions with different probabilities?

Tags: matlab, math, probability, probability-theory

I am working on a AI algorithm. first when program runs a random solution is generated from which ,in first iteration of the program 10 solution vectors are created, by analyzing these solutions we could give each of them a probability ( highest , second highest, third highest and so on) towards the optimal solution , for the second input of the program I want it to be a vector (possible solution) obtained from those 10 vectors previously found. But i need the vector solution to consider all the previous solutions with a different impact depending on their probability ...

```
i.e A=[4.7 ,5.6, 3.5,9 ] b=[-7.9 ,8 ,-2.8 ,4.6] c=[7 ,9.7 , 4,6,3.9] ......
```

i used mean in my program

```
NextPossibleSolution = mean(([A;B;C;]))
```

But do you think mean is the right move ? i don't think because all the solution contributes equal to Next Possible Solution (next input) regardless of their likelihood ...  Please if there is a method formula or anything , Let me know that ... I really need it badly .... A Billion Thanks

Comment: Well, mean is sum with equal weights (1/N). Logical extension would be sum with unequal weights, proportional to probabilities. Sum_i(w_i*Vec_i)/Sum_i(w_i)